# while making ssh connection in node js why is a latter code executing before the ssh connection is made

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ssh, synchronous

I have written following code:

```
var Client = require('ssh2').Client;

var info={
    errors:'',
    stdout:'',
    stderr:''
};

conn=new Client();

conn.on('ready',()=>{
    console.log('entering...');
    conn.exec('ls',(err,stream)=>{
        if(err) info.errors=err;
        stream.on('close',(code,signal)=>{
            console.log('leaving: code:'+code+' signal:'+signal);
        });
        stream.on('data',(data)=>{
            info.stdout=data;
        }).stderr.on('data',(data)=>{
            info.stderr=data;
        });
    });

}).connect({
    host: ip,
    port: 22,
    username: u,
    password: p
});

//this gets printed earlier 
console.log(info);
```

so in the above code connects to a server and executes a command and updates the object `info` with the output of the executed command so after i run this code it enters and also executes the code and what is expect is it'll console.log `info` with the updated values but what i get is first the un-updated `info` and then the above code exectes. 
Can anyone help me out in understanding why this is happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Though `console.log(info);` is at the bottom of the program, it will get executed before the other **async methods** are executed and hence will have the `info` object not updated.

`conn.on('ready',()=>{...`
`stream.on('data',(data)=>{...`

are all async functions which will be queued up in the Event Queue to be handled after they are resolved and the queue is free.

You could choose  to use `console.log(info)` inside each of the async method's call back instead.

```
conn.on('ready',()=>{
    console.log('entering...');
    conn.exec('ls',(err,stream)=>{
        if(err) {
         info.errors=err;

         console.log(info);

        }
        stream.on('close',(code,signal)=>{
            console.log('leaving: code:'+code+' signal:'+signal);
        });
        stream.on('data',(data)=>{
            info.stdout=data;

            console.log(info);

        }).stderr.on('data',(data)=>{
            info.stderr=data;

            console.log(info);

        });
    });

}).connect({
    host: ip,
    port: 22,
    username: u,
    password: p
});
```

This way, whenever you're **receiving data** or **an error occurs**, your `info` object will be receiving the right message and then you can log them to console.